# How can I "distribute" a quantity of "items" to a list of objects with an equal attribute in a round robin fashion?

Tags: c#, list

I am unsure how better to title my question, but I'll give a better description.

Let's say I need to distribute a limited quantity of items among a list of objects (called `agent`s) where each object has two (relevant) attributes, those being a double `agent.price` and an int `agent.quantity`. `agent.quantity` refers to how many "items" this object "wants" and `agent.price` refers to the price it will pay per item.

Now, the way my code is set up is that often times, a lot of `agent`s will have equivalent `price` attributes, and the way I am distributing the items is that the first `agent` with the highest price will have their entire `quantity` attribute fulfilled before any other `agent` with the same price. That is undesirable.

What I want to happen is that the quantity is distributed in a round robin fashion.

E.g.: let's say agents A and B both have a `price` of $1.00 but A has a `quantity` of 5 and B a `quantity` of 3, and there is only a total of 5 items to give to the agents. Given that both agents are willing to pay equal amounts for the items, I would rather A get 3 items and B get 2 items (or vice-versa) rather than A getting all of the items.

I have come up with a crude implementation of this, but I was wondering if there was a better implementation or if my implementation is flawed.

```
int indexForSamePriceLevel = 0;
int priceIndex = 0;

while (qToDistribute > 0) 
{
  if (agents[indexForSamePriceLevel].quantity > 0) 
  {
    agents[indexForSamePriceLevel].quantity--;
    qToDistribute--;
  }

  if (indexForSamePriceLevel + 1 != agents.Count) 
  {
    if (agents[indexForSamePriceLevel + 1].price == agents[priceIndex].price)
      indexForSamePriceLevel++;
    else 
    {
      if (agents[indexForSamePriceLevel].quantity == 0) 
      {
        indexForSamePriceLevel++;
        priceIndex = indexForSamePriceLevel;
        continue;
      } 
      else
        indexForSamePriceLevel = priceIndex;
    }
  } 
  else 
  {
    if (agents[indexForSamePriceLevel].quantity == 0) 
    {
      indexForSamePriceLevel++;
      priceIndex = indexForSamePriceLevel;
      continue;
    } 
    else
      indexForSamePriceLevel = priceIndex;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No code, just design thinking...

Assign all `agent`s to be prioritised a `weight` attribute where `weight = price * quantity`? Each `agent` gets allocated `weight / totalWeights * totalAvailable` items.

Beware of integer vs floating point arithmetic and round/truncate appropriately.

In the pic below (Excel) I used `=ROUND(weight/totalWeight*qtyAvailable,0)`

You will come up (1) one item short or (2) items spare, in which case you (1) allocate one less to the last agent or (2) run again to allocate left-overs (after agent quantities are adjusted).

[image]

This is an example of how to think about solving, the only challenge I can see is arranging the weighting formula to favour your (variable?) priorities which you haven't described.

Comment: The thing is that there will be other `agent`s in the list with different `agent.price`s and I don't want to distribute items to those `agent`s with the lowest/highest `agent.price`s (depends on the situation) first. Your solution would result in an `agent` that has a `agent.quantity` of 2 and a `agent.price` of 2 getting items before another `agent` with 1 and 5 of those attributes respectively, and that is undesirable for me.

Comment: @MrMineHeads: I believe the principle is solid and have updated the answer.  Hope I'm not missing the point.

Comment: What you are creating is similar to the highest averages method used in the allocation of seats in elections (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highest_averages_method). I am aware of that and it is not a solution to my problem because there are a max amount of items that can be distributed to an `agent` (the `agent.quantity`) and I am prioritizing the `agent.price` over any calculated weight.

Answer (score 0):

So, first, I'd get a new list of all the agents that share the same price. Here is an example on how to do that:

e.g.

```
var priceToDistribute = 0; //You get to determine this number, but I'd recommend looping through each agent's price for it.
List<agent> SamePriceAgents = new List<agent>();

foreach(var agent in agents)
{
    if(agent.price == priceToDistribute)
        SamePriceAgents.add(agent);
}
```

This will loop through every agent, and add the ones that have the price you're distributing to the new list.

Then, loop through that list, and get the total quantity that they all share. Here's an example of how to do this.

```
int quantityForPrice;

foreach(var agent in SamePriceAgents)
{
    quantityForPrice += agent.quantity;
}
```

Finally, if the quantity of those agents is greater than the quantity to distribute, loop through the new list until you're out of items to distribute. Here's an example of what that could look like:

```
if (qToDistribute < quantityForPrice)
{
    DistributeToPriceRange();
}

void DistributeToPriceRange()
{
    while(qToDistribute > 0)
    {
        foreach(var agent in SamePriceAgents)
        {
            if(qToDistribute > 0 && agent.quantity > 0)
            {
                agent.quantity--; //I'm not sure how you give them and item, so this is just a placeholder for that
                qToDistribute--;
            }
            if(qToDistribute == 0)
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

This will loop through each agent that shares a price, and give them all an item one at a time, while taking away from the amount left, making sure to not give them more than they want/need/can take/etc.

Comment: I am not setting a price and looking if `agent`s match it, but rather sorting the list of `agent`s by their `agent.price` attribute and distributing a limited amount of "items" from lowest/highest `agent.price` to the opposite. If a group of `agent`s have an equal `agent.price` but not an amount of items to satisfy all of them, I want to distribute the items between them such that it doesn't go to the first `agent` in the group but rather distributes it round robin style.

Comment: Ahh, okay. I'll edit my anser to match that

Comment: I will look into your solution in a bit, thank you.